# Date conversion in xforms

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have following data instance which has date node (transaction-date) bound to a date picker (input).

By default its storing the date in CCYY-MM-DD format. I would like to have another node (temp-transaction-date) which will be updated in MMM/DD/CCYY format in xforms-value-changed event.

```
  <xforms:instance id="form-instance">
      <attributes>
         <transaction-date></transaction-date>
         <temp-transaction-date></temp-transaction-date>
      </attributes>
  </xforms:instance>


  <xforms:bind id="transaction-date" nodeset="instance('form-instance')/transaction-date" type="xforms:date" />



  <td>
     <xforms:input bind="transaction-date">
        <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-value-changed">
            <xforms:setvalue ref="instance('form-instance')/temp-transaction-date" value="?"/>
        </xforms:action>
     </xforms:input>
  </td>
```

Please let me know how can i set the value in the format of Mar/09/2011 or is there an alternate way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `<xforms:bind calculate="…">` and the function `format-date()`:

```
<xforms:bind nodeset="temp-transaction-date"
    calculate="format-date(../transaction-date), '[MNn,*-3]/[D01]/[Y]')"/>
```